# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints on a hidden view controller iOS

Tags: ios, constraints, viewcontroller

I have a view controller that is presented to the user on application start up. Autolayout defines the position of on screen objects. This view controller is set to only support portrait using...

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Pressing a button causes the app to segue to a UINavigationController which supports all orientations. Now, when I rotate my phone the trace throws out the warning:

"Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

The constraint warnings that follow all relate to the hidden first view controller. The on-screen objects don't fit on the screen in the landscape orientation, hence the reason for the warning. It seems that supportedInterfaceOrientations is called on the UINavigationController and no longer called at all on the first view controller. This doesn't happen on iOS 7, I've only noticed it since upgrading to iOS 8.

So my questions are:

1. Is there anyway to prevent this?
2. Does it matter (since there's no visible effect), will Apple reject an app on these grounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress this warning I disabled autolayout. I wasn't aware of 'springs, and struts' which is perfectly adequate to express this screen's layout. For noobs like me, this can be found in the size inspector in interface builder.